# Retrieve old version of a file without changing working copy parent

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs, revert

How do you get a copy of an earlier revision of a file in Mercurial without making that the new default working copy of the file in your workspace?

I've found the `hg revert` command and I think it does what I want but I'm not sure.

I need to get a copy of an earlier revision of my code to work with for a few minutes. But I don't want to disturb the current version which is working fine.

So I was going to do this:

```
hg revert -r 10 myfile.pls
```

Is there a way to output it to a different directory so my current working version of the file is not disturbed? Something like:

```
hg revert -r 10 myfile.pls > c:\temp\dump\myfile_revision10.pls
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [cat command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#cat) can be used to retrieve any revision of a file:

```
$ hg cat -r 10 myfile.pls
```

You can redirect the output to another file with

```
$ hg cat -r 10 myfile.pls > old.pls
```

or by using the `--output` flag. If you need to do this for several files, then take a look at the [archive command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#archive), which can do this for an entire project, e.g.,

```
$ hg archive -r 10 ../revision-10
```

This creates the folder `revision-10` which contains a snapshot of your repository as it looked in revision 10.

However, most of the time you should just use the [update command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) to checkout an earlier revision. Update is the command you use to bring the working copy up to date after pulling in new changes, but the command can also be used to make your working copy *outdated* if needed. So

```
$ hg update -r 10   # go back
(look at your files, test, etc...)
$ hg update         # go back to the tip
```

Comment: Thanks for the useful and *concise* description of `update`! I was a bit jittery before using the update command (as was coriolanus I suppose).

Answer (score 9):

The command you use is this:

```
hg cat -r 10 myfile.pls > C:\temp\dump\myfile_revision10.pls
```

Knowing a bit of Unix helps with Mercurial commands.  Perhaps `cat` should have a built in alias `print` or something similar.